# j2me post data limit

Tags: post, java-me, limit, httpconnection

is there any limit to send data from j2me device to server. I coded a application to send big data to server from j2me client. it works fine in wtk and sonyericsson emulator. but when i tried same code in real device, I can send only 6K data. then, app throws IOException. every 2K, I run flush function of outputstream to seperate data to chunk type.

anyway, is there anybody to send 20K data from j2me real device to server ? and which model ?

i tried it in SonyEricsson W710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the Mobile Network Operator blocks HTTP POST requests if their body is over 6Kb.

I would try to use a different network to check whether the limit changes (could be less, could be more).

Chunking may also be a bad idea, depending on the mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you posting to?  If IIS, [this fix](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5362159) may help.

Comment: It is weblogic application server.